# Create graphics from Metafile error "out of memory"

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm trying to draw with metafile in GDI+, can any one tell me why my code not work, my file just about 1KB :(

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Metafile img = new Metafile(@"D:\anh.emf");
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);// out of memory exception.
        //g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightYellow, 0, 0, 100, 100);                      
        //pictureBox1.Image = img;
        img.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: An EMF file can potentially be enormous in terms of pixel size even if the file size is small. Could you check the metadata (especially resolution and size) of the file in another tool and make sure they're not silly?

Comment: i'm not sure but if i coment "Metafile img = new Metafile(@"D:\anh.emf");" AND  uncoment "pictureBox1.Image = img;" my image show on pictureBox

Comment: Well, could you make sure...? Try something like IrfanView to look at the file metadata. The PictureBox might optimize things and only create a buffer large enough to contain the visible part only, while a Graphics object will likely try to create one that's big enough to contain the entire image.

Comment: i'm try to open in corel draw and it's ok. :(

Comment: The point was to open the file in something that shows the exact metadata in the file, not just look at the picture.

Comment: I think @MattiVirkkunen is right. What does img.GetMetafileHeader().Bounds look like?